# Remove remote branch and syncing

Tags: git, git-branch

When deleting a branch from remote and local other people working in that repo
are affected. If someone has the deleted branch local I guess they can push it back right?
How is this syncing handled?

Comment: What "syncing" are you referring to?

Comment: @junkangli:Should others do any manual update in their local repo?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: @kvk30: From your link seems that people need to run `git fetch --all --prune` in their machines?

Comment: @Jim yeah it was worked for me, If It didn't work for you let me know.

Answer (score 1):

> When deleting a branch from remote and local other people working in that repo are affected. If someone has the deleted branch local I guess they can push it back right?

Yes, someone else who has the local branch, which got deleted in the remote, can push it to remote.

Git commit hash is actually a hash of the commit object that contains information including the hash of the commit before it. That is how the git commit history is generated.

Other people who also has the local branch will just need to set their remote tracking branch to the new "restored" branch, using the command:

```
git branch branch_name -u your_new_remote/branch_name
```

Comment: Are you asking for the command to change the upstream branch to be tracked?

Comment: Ah so need for them to prune or something?

Comment: The `prune` option is to remove stale branches that no longer exist in the remote. The solution I provided replaces the old remote branch to the new one. So, people who want to continue working on that branch can use the command I provided, and people who do not want to continue working on that branch can prune the old branch.